# I want to select a random background song out of a number of songs for my react app

Tags: reactjs

Each time the user loads the app a different song should play. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a list of songs array;

```js
const songsCollections = ['http://www.music.helsinki.fi/tmt/opetus/uusmedia/esim/a2002011001-e02.wav', 'http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples_1w72b820/2563.mp3', 'http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples_1w72b820/2558.mp3'];

const getRandomFromRange = (min, max) => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
};

const randomSongIndex = getRandomFromRange(0, songsCollections.length);

console.log('Random song index is ', randomSongIndex)

const randomSong = songsCollections[randomSongIndex];
new Audio(randomSong).play()
```

You need to have an array of your songs, then using a random function pick a random song & use Javascript's Audio method to `play()` the chose song.